# wp_authenticate() returns Error for valid username and password, in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom lo gin form. i am using wp_authenticate() for authentication, but it returns error for valid username and password. Kindly suggest where i might have done mistake.
thanks.
Below  is code,

```
$user_name = sanitize_user($_POST['log']);
$user_pass = $_POST['pwd'];
$user = wp_authenticate_user($user_name, $user_pass);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$creds = array();
$creds['user_login'] = $user_name;
$creds['user_password'] = $user_pass;
$creds['remember'] = true; //Or false

$user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
if ( is_wp_error($user) ){
   //There is an error logging in
   echo $user->get_error_message();
}else{
   //Login successfull
}
```